# Rails, Drop column from table and delegate it to an associated table and use the delegated column within where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm currently working on a product where for some reaasons we decided to destroy the `email` column from a specific table and then delegate that column to an associated table using active record delegate method

https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

My question here will be about what is the approach to follow in order to make sure that all the where clauses that uses the `email` colum are also delegated as well. Because it's basically need a lot of time to check all the places where we used `table.where(dropped_column: value`)

**Example**

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact
  delegate :email, to: :contact
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :station
end
```

I know that it is possible to switch all the queries from `Station.where(email: value)` to `Station.joins(:contact).where('contacts.email': value)` but this approach will take very long and also `where` clause can be written in many different ways so searching throught the code source and updating all of them is not efficient enough to cover all the cases.

If anyone faced a similar situation and managed to solved in way that saves us time and bugs I will be very glad to hear what are the approaches you followed.

Thanks.

Rails version: '5.2.3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the approach to follow in order to make sure that all the where clauses that uses the email column are also delegated as well

You cannot "delegate" SQL commands. You need to update them all.

> I know that it is possible to switch all the queries from `Station.where(email: value)` to `Station.joins(:contact).where('contacts.email': value)` but this approach will take very long

Yep, that's what you'll need to do, sorry!

> If anyone face a similar situation and managed to solved in way that saves us time and bugs I will be very glad to hear what are the approaches you followd.

Before *dropping* the column, you can first do this:

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.ignored_columns = ['email']

  has_one :contact
  delegate :email, to: :contact

  # ...
end
```

This way, you can stop the application from being able to access the column, without actually deleting it from the database (like a 'soft delete'), which makes it easy to revert.

Do this on a branch, and make all the specs green. (If you have good test coverage, you're done! But if your coverage is poor, there may be errors after deploying...)

If it goes wrong after deploying, you *could* revert the whole PR, or just comment out the `ignored_columns` again, temporarily, while you push fixes.

Then finally, once your application is running smoothly without errors, drop the column.

Comment: This works because rails does not (unless you execute raw SQL!) fetch data via `select * from table_name`; instead, it always declares each column explicitly like `select table_name.col1, table_name.col2, table_name.col3 from table_name`. So if you tell rails to explicitly *ignore* a column then any SQL queries referencing that column should fail.

Comment: Ignoring the column is a good way to soft-delete it, before dropping it.